# Realizar links dinámicos con ajax, par asp.net core MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

tengo una función para realizar links dinámicos , el problema es que al momento de crearlos no me lo toma como link dejo lo que he realizado hasta el momento :

```
    function getprueba() {
        var folio = $('#numerofolio').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/Prueba2?tick=" + folio,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "null") {
                    alert("no está funcionando");
                }                    
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                    var nombre = result[i].ruta.split("/");
                    var separe = nombre[8];
                    var links = "<a  asp-controller=\"User\"  asp-action=\"Descarga\"  asp-route-ruta=\""+result[i].ruta +"\">" + separe + "</a>"
        document.getElementById("listajson").innerHTML = links;


                }



            },

            error: function (err) {
                alert("error" + err);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

El problema aparece en está linea :

```
<a  asp-controller=\"User\"  asp-action=\"Descarga\"  asp-route-ruta=\""+result[i].ruta +"\">" + separe + "</a>"
```

No me direcciona al controlador ni a la acción. Alguien puede asesorarme por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Chemox si el erro es solo esto: " + separe + "

que me imagino que sale de aquí:

```
var links = "" + separe + "" document.getElementById("listajson").innerHTML = links;
```

creo que la primer solucion es quitar las comillas:

```
var links = separe + document.getElementById("listajson").innerHTML = links;
```

Si revisas tu pregunta y la editas para dar mas información por que me parece un poco confusa te podremos ayudar mas, suerte y saludos.

Comment: Que tal ya corregí eso quedo así :var links = "<a asp-controller=\"User\"  asp-action=\"Descarga\"  asp-route-ruta=\""+result[i].ruta+"\">"+separe+"</a>"

Comment: Pero sigue el problema, no me los toma como links.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y hasta abajo pon como sale ahora, para seguirte ayudando

Comment: Viendo tu código, me imagino que en alguna parte estas escapando las " (comillas dobles) así \" y se me hace que ese es tu problema también, quitarle el \ y me avisas como te va

Answer (score 0):

Ya revise junto con un compañero, el error es que generamos los links dentro de la función, la vista que usamos no detecta la sintaxis , lo que hicimos fue esto :

```
@Html.ActionLink("prueba", "Descarga", new { ruta = "//mi_ruta_server/carpeta$/carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/carpeta4/mi_archivo"}, "User");
```

aun no termino pero el error ya no aparece, gracias por sus comentarios.